# Print String in Inverse Pyramid

Tags: java

```
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
String x;
int y;
System.out.println("Enter the String : ");
x = scnr.nextLine();
y = x.length();

for(int i=0; i<y; i++) {

   for(int j=0; j <i; j++) {
       System.out.printf("%c ",x.charAt(j));
   }

   System.out.printf("%c\n",x.charAt(i));
}
```

If you entered "Kevin" it would print
K
KE
KEV
KEVI
KEVIN going down

I am looking for it to print the full word first and then remove a letter as you go down
thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would just use a simple `for` loop here:

```java
System.out.println("Enter the String : ");
String x = scnr.nextLine();
for (int i=0; i < x.length(); ++i) {
    System.out.println(x.substring(0, x.length()-i));
}
```

For an input of `KEVIN`, the output from the above would be:

```
KEVIN
KEVI
KEV
KE
K
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use two-loop then this will be the approach.

```
System.out.println("Enter the String : ");
x = scnr.nextLine();

for(int i=0;i < x.length(); i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < x.length() - i ; j++) {
        System.out.print(x.charAt(j));
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

output:

```
KEVIN
KEVI
KEV
KE
K
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using simple recursion

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        inversePyramid("KEVIN");
    }

    public static void inversePyramid(String s){
        if(s.length()>1) {
            inversePyramid(s.substring(0, s.length()-1));
        }
        System.out.print(s+" ");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

public class Home{

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
       String x;
       int y;
    System.out.println("Enter the String : ");
       x = scnr.nextLine();
       y = x.length();
       for(int i=0; i<y;i++){

           for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
               System.out.printf("%c ",x.charAt(j));
           }
           System.out.printf("%c\n",x.charAt(y-1));
       }
}
```

}

Comment: instead of printing charAt(i) , print x,charAt(y-1)